# How to use DbFunctions in IQueryable for Lucene Index search

Tags: c#, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

I am using following code to get result from Lucene index.

```
    using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("my_profile_index").CreateSearchContext())
    {
        IQueryable<ProfileSearchItem> query = from profile in context.GetQueryable<ProfileSearchItem>()
                                              where profile.LastName.Equals("Zafar")
                                              let diffYears = DbFunctions.DiffYears(profile.Birthdate, DateTime.Today)
                                              select profile;
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

I get exception because of `DbFunctions.DiffYears`:

```
Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

I get exactly one record if I don't use the `DbFunctions` in above query. I would like to know how to use `DbFunctions` while searching indexes. This is just a sample query, my only objective is as mentioned in title.

`ProfileSearchItem` class:

```
public class ProfileSearchItem
    {
        [IndexField("_group")]
        public string ItemId { get; set; }

        [IndexField("_language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }

        [IndexField("birthdate")]
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

        [IndexField("first_name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [IndexField("last_name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the query likes having functions inside it and the query parser is trying to convert this into something.

In your case you could just do the calculation of years difference after the query on the POCO.

Have a property on your ProfileSearchItem POCO;

```
public int YearsDifference { get { return Datetime.Now.Year - Birthdate.Year;} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The date fields are kept as string in Lucene like 20170308 so many of the data methods won't work even simple ones like comparing [DateField].Year so I guess the DbFunctions.DiffYears is doing some lambda expressions and using date method to populate the result.

Have a look on https://ggullentops.blogspot.com.au/2015/12/sitecore-lucene-index-and-datetime.html and you might get a better view